# How to add git commits in JIRA

Tags: git, jira

If I have added some commits in git repository , How would I see those commits in linked JIRA story ?

If I have some code repository in GIT say "ABC" and I have account in JIRA for logging bugs , story and test. 
I have created some test case (say some JIRA id -XXX)and after it I have automated the test case , to track the code of this test case I wanted to see this commits corresponding to JIRA id - XXX

Tried way :
One way I know is , add the JIRA id in commit message while commit to git then this is automatically comes in commits list under that JIRA id.

I am looking for the solution which will allow me to merge the commits later on under that JIRA ID

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is JIRA webhooks.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/managing-webhooks-867028229.html

Comment: Apparently you need to have the webhook open from your Jira server to a repo on your  git server for JIRA to receive commit notifications, as an example, about a JIRA task when the commit message starts with the JIRA ticket name.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, adding the JIRA ID to the commit message is the only way. I don't see any JIRA functionality for adding commits otherwise.